# Reading a list of emails from a Google Sheet, but only receiving the string "Range" from every supposed email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am making a program to send an email to a random 5 people, from a list,  every day. I don't want to send an email to the same person more than once a week, so I am saving the current list of emails (variable cdata) to cells A1 to A32 on a sheet, and removing the people I've sent an email to. I apologize if my code is messy or bad, this is the first big project I've done with Google apps Script.

I've looked at the documentation, but I cannot seem to find anything.

```js
function Send() {
  for (var ii = 0; ii < 3; ii ++) {
    //init
    var data = ["List of emails"]
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 32 + 1);
    var email = data[ran];
    var sub = "Subject";
    var body = "Body"

    //get data from sheet
    var a = "'Script Data Storage'!A" + (ran + 1)

    // compose cdata
    var cdata = []

    for (var iii = 0; iii < data.length; iii++) {
      var a = "'Script Data Storage'!A" + (iii + 1)
      // VV Below line returning string "range" and nothing else
      cdata.push(SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bMTD83N5lxYAaBpQtkvpt_xaPKccl7h3rz3NR3Viv90/edit#gid=0').getRange(a).getValue());
    }
    //run

    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, sub, body)

    //remove item from cdata

    //find position of item to remove
    for( var i = 0; i < cdata.length; i++){ 
      if ( cdata[i] === email ) {
        var rem = cdata.splice(i, 1); 
      }
    }
    //remove item
    for( var i = 0; i < cdata.length; i++){ 
      if ( cdata[i] === rem) {
        cdata.splice(i, 1); 
      }

      //open sheet and save Data to Cell A1-A32

      for(var i = 0; i < cdata.length; i++) {
        var a = "'Script Data Storage'!A" + (i + 1)
        SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bMTD83N5lxYAaBpQtkvpt_xaPKccl7h3rz3NR3Viv90/edit#gid=0').getRange(a).setValue(cdata[i]);        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect cdata to be a list of emails, but all I get is ["Range","Range","Range",.."Range"]

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r97oC.png)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, at 1st for loop, it seems that the range object is pushed to the array of `cdata`. If you want to retrieve the value from the range, for example as one of several modifications, how about modifying to `cdata.push(SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bMTD83N5lxYAaBpQtkvpt_xaPKccl7h3rz3NR3Viv90/edit#gid=0').getRange(a).getValue());`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())

Comment: I changed the code and ran it, but it didn't change anything. It still outputs the ["Range"] array.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Can you provide the script for completely replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can do, please update your question.

Comment: *changed the code and ran it, but it didn't change anything. It still outputs the ["Range"] array.* That's not possible. Check again. [Edit] your question to include the modified code as suggested

Comment: Tanaike is correct. `.getValue()` does not return a range so if you have updated your code as suggested then you will not be getting your ["Range"] array.

Comment: I updated it with my whole code.

Comment: Have you run your code since updating it?

Comment: Yes. Google sheets says, "Last edit was made seconds ago by Garrett Keneau"

Comment: In your updated script, `GmailApp.sendEmail(email, sub, body)` doesn't use the variable of `cdata`, and `body` is always `"Body"`. But you are saying `only receiving the string “Range” from every supposed email`. I cannot understand about this situation. So can you provide the method for completely replicating your issue? If I misunderstood your situation, please tell me. By the way, can I ask you that how you ran the the function of `Send()`?

Comment: The variable `email` is being updated by the lines 
 `var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 32 + 1);
    var email = data[ran];`

I have been running it by clicking the save button, then clicking the play button. Is there another way to run it?

By saying I am receiving the "range" string, I meant that I was storing in a spreadsheet, and that every time I run it, all the cells are updated to "Range". Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the output from the spreadsheet.

Comment: @GarrettKeneau try adding `Logger.log(cdata);` before and after your `cdata.push(...)` line and see what is posted in the log.